# accident detection project using webcam

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, webcam

I am getting an error in the code below. I want to take input from the webcam and if any accident occurs then it will shows that accident occurs. But with the code below I am not even getting camera video feed. It shows the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE'
```

If I change it to `cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL` then it shows this error:

```
C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:9748: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
```

Sometimes it turns on my laptop camera LED, and I want take video from the webcam.

```
#Import necessary packages
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math, operator

#Function to find difference in frames
def diffImg(t0, t1, t2):
  d1 = cv2.absdiff(t2, t1)    
  d2 = cv2.absdiff(t1, t0)
  return cv2.bitwise_and(d1, d2)

j=1
#Import video from webcam
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#Creating window to display 
winName = "Accident Detector"
cv2.namedWindow(winName, cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

#Reading frames at multiple instances from webcam to different variables
t_minus = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
t = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
t_plus = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)


while True:
  #Display video out through the window we created
  cv2.imshow( winName, diffImg(t_minus, t, t_plus) )

  #Calling function diffImg() and assign the return value to 'p'
  p=diffImg(t_minus, t, t_plus)

  #Writing 'p' to a directory
  cv2.imwrite("D:\photos\shot.jpg",p)

  #From Python Image Library(PIL) import Image class
  from PIL import Image

  #Open image from the directories and returns it's histogram's
  h1 = Image.open("D:\motionpic\shot"+str(j)+".jpg").histogram()
  h2 = Image.open("D:\photos\shot.jpg").histogram()
  j=j+1

  #Finding rms value of the two images opened before        
  rms = math.sqrt(reduce(operator.add,map(lambda a,b: (a-b)**2, h1, h2))/len(h1))  
  print int(rms)

  #If the RMS value of the images are under our limit 
  if (rms<250):
    #Then there is a similarity between images. i.e., Scene similar to an accident is found
    print "accident\a"


  #Updates the frames
  t_minus = t
  t = t_plus
  t_plus = cv2.cvtColor(cam.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

  #Destroys the window after key press
  key = cv2.waitKey(10)
  if key == 27:
    cv2.destroyWindow(winName)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to create a new window is

```
cv2.namedWindow(winName, cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
```

Also the camera frames should be read under the while loop.

Comment: i tried this but i am getting error on same line 
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2766, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Anuj\\shot1.jpg'      showing this error... but I have created this directory still it says that i don't have one..  Its captures the photo but its doesn't capture the actual photo its completely black and the frame window doesn't respond there after.